# AWS Send SNS message from lambda at a specified time

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a lambda function `lambda1` that gets triggered by an API call and computes the parameters for another job downstream that will be handled by a different function `lambda2`.

The resources required to complete the downstream job are not available immediately and will become available at some future time `datetime1` which is also calculated by `lambda1`.

How do I make `lambda1` schedule a message in an SNS topic that will be sent out at `datetime1` instead of going out immediately? The message sent out at the correct time will then trigger `lambda2` which will find all the resources in place and execute correctly.

Is there a better way of doing this instead of SNS?

Both `lambda1` and `lambda2` are written in Python 3.8

Comment: Sns has no delivery delay.   Sqs does however.   So have your lambda queue an sqs message with the proper delay,  and connect the sqs queue to a lambda that sends to sns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be better off using the AWS Step Functions. Step functions are generally used for orchestrating jobs with multiple Lambda functions involved and they support the `wait state` that you need to run a job at a specific time.

Basically, you will create multiple states. One of the states will be `wait state` where you will input the wait condition (timestamp at which it will stop waiting). This is what you will send from Lambda1. The next state would be `task state` which will be your Lambda2.

Comment: Is this the recommended way if the wait time is several days?

Comment: Yes, step functions should be able to handle jobs with waiting of up to a year